# Goland: run arbitrary code quality tool, get clickable results

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

I have an (in-house) code quality tool that produces results like this, when run from the shell:

```
fooer/quxxer_bulk_stuff.go:40:16: rhubarb rhubarb...
fooer/quxxer_load.go:22:16: rhubarb rhubarb...
fooer/quxxer_load.go:78:16: rhubarb rhubarb...
```

How do I configure Goland so that I can run the tool *on demand* (i.e. not a File Watcher) and have the results appear in a run window? Also, I want to be able to click on a line in the results and jump to the referenced file and line, so I can review/fix the problem.

*(Goland version 2019.1, Build #GO-191.6183.86)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it as an external tool in Settings | External Tools. To get clickable results, define an output filter (`$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:$COLUMN$:.*` should work for your case). See the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-create-edit-copy-tool-dialog.html) for more information.

Comment: Goland is such a large (and great) product, I'm still learning all the nooks and crannies :-)